# How to represent a single point on a matlplotlib plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a graph which represents the sentiments of the values in a column of pandas dataframe. Given a sentence, I want to highlight the corresponding sentiment value on the graph/plot. I am looking for an output similar to the image below:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pyplot.scatter` and pass single values in for `x` and `y`. Here's an example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

x_data = np.linspace(0,3.5,100)
y_data = [-x * (x - 3.2) for x in x_data]

plt.plot(x_data, y_data, color='#0000ff', zorder=0)

x_point = x_data[20]
y_point = y_data[20]

plt.scatter(x_point, y_point, color='#ff0000', zorder=1)
```

Produces:
[image]